# Dynamic List in JasperReports 3.6 with JavaBean datasource

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using *iReport 3.6*.

I have a JavaBean class which has the following code:

```
private Collection<String> containerNumber;

  public Collection<String> getContainerNumber()
  {    return containerNumber;  }


  public void setContainerNumber(Collection<String> pContainerNumber)
  {    this.containerNumber = pContainerNumber;  }
```

When I let *iReport 3.6* read this *JavaBean* it sees a Collection (which is what i want). But I want to show this collection in my report as a dynamic list/field. So when the *setContainNumber* sets 1 container number, the report shows 1 container. When the *setContainerNumber* sets 10 containers, the report shows 10 containers. Underneath my containers in my report, i have more fields, when it shows 10 containers, these fields should drop 10 container spaces. When it shows 1 container, these fields should drop 1 container space.

*My question*: How do I show a dynamic list with a Collection of Strings as *JavaBean* datasource?